# Verify certificate from SQL Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, x509certificate, sqlconnection

In the following scenario:

- SQL Server 2012 with a certificate with server/client authentication. This certificate is used to force encrypted connection. This seems to work, because when I enable/disable the force encrypted option I see by running the SQL statement `select * from sys.dm_exec_connections` the encrypt option set to true/false.
- A client machine has to verify that the `SqlConnection` is done under a valid certificate with the server authentication key.

I found some info about `ServicePointManager`, but I am not able to make it work with a `SqlConnection`.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = PinCertificate;
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/");
wr.GetResponse();

.....

private bool PinCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
                                      X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    byte[] chash = certificate.GetCertHash();
    //.... this certificate contains the info ...
    var enhancedKeyExtensions = cert.Extensions.OfType<X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension>().FirstOrDefault();
    bool valid = false;

    if (enhancedKeyExtensions != null)
    {
        X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension ext = (X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension)enhancedKeyExtensions;
        OidCollection oids = ext.EnhancedKeyUsages;

        foreach (Oid oid in oids)
        {
            valid = oid.Value.Equals("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1");

            if (valid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!valid)
        MessageBox.Show("No server authentification found!");
}
```

Any idea how to stablish a `SqlConnection` and check that the certificate that is used there contains the key usage extensions I need?

Comment: Might not be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691955/net-sqlconnection-server-authentication-and-certificate-pinning

Comment: I see, that link I checked and I was reading it, but I thought there should be a workaround. Seems there is no.